# How to dispose Libgdx Texture via Sprite object

Tags: java, libgdx

The standad way of creating a sprite in LibGDX is this

```
Texture texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("myTexture.jpb");
Srite sprite = new Sprite(texture);
```

There is also another shorter way

```
Sprite sprite = new Sprite(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("myTexture.jpb"));
```

Now the second way is much more efficient as when you use a lot of different textures and sprites it really saves a lot of lines of code. The problem though, is that I can't find a way to dispose the textures that the sprites use when I don't need them anymore, as the the Sprite class does not implement the Disposable interface and thus it does't have a dispose() function.

Can you think of  any way I can dispose the Texture given the fact that I don't have a direct reference to it like I do if I choose the first way of declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Sprite` is a subclass of `TextureRegion`, so it has a [`getTexture()` method](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/TextureRegion.html#getTexture--) to get at the underlying texture object.

The [Sprite API docs](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.html) make this pretty obtuse (its just referenced in the "Methods inherited from .." section).

Comment: Remember to mark an answer when you find a solution from it.

Comment: @exophrenik, glad to help!  You can accept an answer by clicking the checkmark outline to the left (under the vote count on the left).  Marking a question as "answered" like this, makes it easier for folks to find useful answers and easier for folks to find questions that still need more/better answers.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer.  Thanks!